# Deleting elements with .on event handler and no page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple data that I am pulling from a phpMyAdmin database. I populate the div with this data and then have `X` to delete the item from the page. The delete happens without a problem but it is not a live event. I have to reload the page before I can the element deleted. Why is that happening? I have specify the `on` event to occur when the `X` is clicked to delete item but nothing happens.

**Html**

```
<div id="listInserts">
    dog<a class="del" rel="1" href="#">X</a>
    cat<a class="del" rel="2" href="#">X</a>
    bird<a class="del" rel="3" href="#">X</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    $.get('dashboard/xhrGetListings', function(o) {
     //Pulling results from database
        for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
        {
            $('#listInserts').append('<div>' + o[i].text + '<a class="del" rel="'+o[i].id+'" href="#">X</a></div>');
        }
     //Perform live delete
        $('#listInserts').on('click', 'a.del', function(e) {
            var delItem = $(this);
            var id = $(this).attr('rel');

            $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {'id': id}, function(o) {
                delItem.parent().remove();
            }, 'json');

            return false;
        });

    }, 'json');

});
```

Comment: seems to me that `delItem.parent()` is your container, actually

Comment: @IgorDymov sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: He means that the line `delItem.parent().remove();` tries to delete the parent node of the `<a> the clicked link</a>` The next html tag is the surrounding `<div id='listInserts'>` But this is not the node that you want to delete.

Comment: Could you solve the issue? What kind of errors do you get in the chrome dev conosole?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use delegate from jquery. You just set it up at the top of the page like an event listener.

```
$('body').delegate('.del', 'click', function(e) { 
        var delItem = $(this);
        var id = $(this).attr('rel');

        $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {'id': id}, function(o) {
            delItem.parent().remove();
        }, 'json');

        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a local copy of your code. 
Als IgorDymov pointed out the line `delItem.parent().remove();` tries to delete the parent node of your link. If you change the code to

```
<div id="listInserts">
<ul>
        <li>dog      <a class="del" rel="1" href="#">X</a></li>
        <li>cat      <a class="del" rel="2" href="#">X</a></li>
        <li> bird      <a class="del" rel="3" href="#">X</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This way you delete the li, which is the parent node for your link.

Are you sure that the path to `dashboard/xhrDeleteListing` can be resolved? What does the [chrome dev tools console](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI) say after you clicked a link?

There might be another problem. Are you sure that the event handler to delete the items is bound?